# How do I determine which file(s) generate which dependencies for my rpm build?

Tags: dependencies, rpm

I am trying to determine which files in my build produce each of the dependencies for my package. For example, a subset of the requires for my build are:

```
rpm -qp --requires mypackage.rpm
libc.so.6
libm.so.6
perl(strict)
...
```

How can I determine which file(s) in my build generated the dependency for `libm.so.6`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is "rpm -qp --filerequire *.rpm".

Another way is to use "echo /path/to/file | /usr/lib/rpm/rpmdeps -R"
with some minor scripting.